# how to add outline enclosing the absolutely positioned child without setting default height on the parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to add border to the entire div and reveal the absolutely positioned child at the same time on mouse hover, since the child is set to absolute adding adding border to the parent ignores the child, so I have set a default height to the parent which is against what I am trying to do.

I have set the child to absolute so that it does not push the below elements on reveal, I want the child to float on top.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content: " ";
 /* Older browser do not support empty content */
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}

body {
 padding: 10rem;
}

.video {
 width: 220px;
 background-color: #fff;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 500ms;
 display: block;
}

.video__details {
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 display: none;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.video:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 outline: 10px solid white;
}

.video:hover .video__details {
 opacity: 1;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="video">
    <!-- Video Main -->
    <div class="video__main">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/220/180" alt="" class="video__img" />
      <p class="video__title">Video Name Video_Name_Eng</p>
      <span class="video__number">Video Number</span>
      <span class="video__ratings">S T A R S</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Video Details -->
    <div class="video__details">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, numquam dolorum! In, eligendi inventore.
      </p>
      <div class="video__viewes">Views 4.6k</div>
      <button class="video__button">Details</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I am trying to acheive : [GIF link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdEnE.jpg)
Fiddle Link of my approach : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0gmL1au5/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

> Removed `outlined` and set `padding`

I don't know where you need outline or not. But this is hows your `gif image` looks like

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content: " ";
 /* Older browser do not support empty content */
 visibility: hidden;
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
}

body {
 padding: 10rem;
}

.video {
 width: 220px;
 background-color: #fff;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 500ms;
 display: block;
  padding: 30px;
}

.video__details {
 width: inherit;
 height: inherit;
 display: none;
 opacity: 0;
 position: absolute;
  bottom: -130px;
  left:0;
}

.video:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
 
}

.video:hover .video__details {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 30px 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 29px 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 13px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="video">
   <!-- Video Main -->
   <div class="video__main">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/220/180" alt="" class="video__img" />
    <p class="video__title">Video Name Video_Name_Eng</p>
    <span class="video__number">Video Number</span>
    <span class="video__ratings">S T A R S</span>
   </div>

   <!-- Video Details -->
   <div class="video__details">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat, numquam
     dolorum! In, eligendi inventore.
    </p>
    <div class="video__viewes">Views 4.6k</div>
    <button class="video__button">Details</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```